# how can phonegap package sencha with signate (keystore)

Tags: extjs, ant, apk, keystore, signature

I package my sencha files with ant debug command, but how the apk can get signature with keystore file.

---

### And also.

Sencha can get signature by insert signature node with keystore for app.json, but can it work for ant command. And how can I check whether the signature is applied or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

got some advice from tutorial as follows.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

---

I add the following key-value within ant.properties file (within up directory of bin)

key.store=path_of_keystore/file_name.keystore

key.alias=alias_of_keystore

key.store.password=as_key_name(the pwd during create keystore by keytool)

key.alias.password=as_key_name

And then, I change the ant debug command to ant release.